# How to create a rounded hexagon with javascript andCANVAS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5-canvas

I created [this codepen](https://codepen.io/programad/pen/wvMNRPy) to show what I got.

[image]

I managed to generate a hexagon avatar with progressbar around it using the awesome open source Hexagon Progress jQuery Plugin from Max Lawrence.

He also helped me to improve his own code a little but I don't want to bother him again.

Maybe someone here can help me to round the corners of this hexagon.

I want it to looks something like this (from the awesome Vikinger Html template) but need to be open source because my software is all open source. I can't use the Vikinger code.

[image]

So far I read that I have to stop the line before the end and add a quadratic curve to the next line start but I could not managed to do that.

His code do something like this on line 505:

```js
ctx.moveTo(this.coordBack[0].x + offset, this.coordBack[0].y + offset);
for(var i = 0; i < this.coordBack.length; i++) {
    ctx.lineTo(this.coordBack[i].x + offset, this.coordBack[i].y + offset);
}
```

Unfortunatelly, I am not that good in javascript or math.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two ways to do this. The easy way, and the long winded, lots of math way.

### Easy rounded corners

To create simple rounded polygons you can use [`ctx.arcTo`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/arcTo). It will do all the math for the corners.

To create the polygon the following functions create a point and a path (array of points)

```
const Point = (x,y) => ({x, y});
function polygon(sides, rad, rot = 0) {
    var i = 0, step = Math.PI * 2 / sides, path = [];
    while (i < sides) {
        path.push(Point(Math.cos(i * step + rot) * rad, Math.sin((i++) * step + rot) * rad));
    }
    return path;
}
```

To create a hexagon. Note that the polygon is centered over its local origin 0,0

```
const hexagon = polygon(6, 100);
```

To render the rounded polygon you need to work from the line segment centers. The following function will stroke the path with the rounded corners.

```
function strokeRoundedPath(cx, cy, path, radius, style, width) {
    ctx.setTransform(1,0,0,1,cx,cy);
    var i = 0;
    const len = path.length
    var p1 = path[i++], p2 = path[i];
    ctx.lineWidth = width;
    ctx.lineCap = "round";
    ctx.strokeStyle = style;
    
    ctx.beginPath();
    
    ctx.lineTo((p1.x + p2.x) / 2, (p1.y + p2.y) / 2);
    while (i <= len) {
        p1 = p2;
        p2 = path[(++i) % len];
        ctx.arcTo(p1.x, p1.y, (p1.x + p2.x) / 2, (p1.y + p2.y) / 2, radius);
    }
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.stroke();
    ctx.setTransform(1,0,0,1,0,0);
}

strokeRoundedPath(200, 200, hexagon, 20, "#000", 18);
```

### Progress bar

Creating a progress bar is not as simple as the starting point can not be on a rounded corner, and moving over the rounded corners will need a lot of math to get the correct coordinates. This will negate the point of using easy `arcTo`and need us to write the equivalent in JS (Way to slack for that today)

### Using line dash for progress

There is however a hack that uses the line dash to create the effect you may be happy with. The snippet demonstrates this

```js
const barWidth = 10;
const cornerRadius = barWidth * 2 + 8;
const polyRadius = 100;
const inset = 1;
const barRadius = polyRadius - barWidth * inset;
var progress = 0.0;
const approxLineLen = barRadius * Math.PI * 2;
const hexBar = polygon(6, barRadius);
const hexPoly = polygon(6, polyRadius);
const hexPolyInner = polygon(6, polyRadius - barWidth * 2 * inset);
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
ctx.setLineDash([approxLineLen]);
loop()


function point(x,y) { return {x, y} }
function polygon(sides, radius, rot = 0) {
    var i = 0;
    const step = Math.PI * 2 / sides, path = [];
    while (i < sides) {
        path.push(point(Math.cos(i * step + rot) * radius, Math.sin((i++) * step + rot) * radius));
    }
    return path;
}
function roundedPath(path, radius) {
    var i = 0, p1 = path[i++], p2 = path[i];
    const len = path.length
    ctx.moveTo((p1.x + p2.x) / 2, (p1.y + p2.y) / 2);
    while (i <= len) {
        p1 = p2;
        p2 = path[(++i) % len];
        ctx.arcTo(p1.x, p1.y, (p1.x + p2.x) / 2, (p1.y + p2.y) / 2, radius);
    }
}
function strokeRoundedPath(cx, cy, path, radius, style, width) {
    ctx.setTransform(1,0,0,1,cx,cy);
    ctx.lineWidth = width;
    ctx.lineCap = "round";
    ctx.strokeStyle = style;
    ctx.beginPath();
    roundedPath(path, radius);
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.stroke();
}
function fillRoundedPath(cx, cy, path, radius, style) {
    ctx.setTransform(1,0,0,1,cx,cy);
    ctx.fillStyle = style;
    ctx.beginPath();
    roundedPath(path, radius);
    ctx.fill();
}
function loop() {
    ctx.setTransform(1,0,0,1,0,0);
    ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
    fillRoundedPath(polyRadius, polyRadius, hexPoly, cornerRadius, "#000");
    fillRoundedPath(polyRadius, polyRadius, hexPolyInner, cornerRadius - barWidth * inset * 2, "#F80");
    ctx.lineDashOffset = approxLineLen - (progress % 1) * approxLineLen;
    strokeRoundedPath(polyRadius, polyRadius, hexBar, cornerRadius - barWidth * inset, "#09C", barWidth);
    progress += 0.005;
    requestAnimationFrame(loop);
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width = "210" height="210"></canvas>
```

Comment: Ok, I got some improvements https://codepen.io/programad/pen/VweReYY. Can you help me to start the progress bar from the top? The goal here is to look like the first codepen but rounded. https://codepen.io/programad/pen/wvMNRPy

Comment: @programad The function polygon has a 3rd optional argument that will rotate the polygon. eg `const hexBar = polygon(6, barRadius, -Math.PI * 0.5)` will rotate the path 90deg CCW